# batch tesseract conversion

Tags: batch, ocr

I am trying to OCR a book using tesseract however I do not want to type each individual page as it is a book near 1000 pages. How would I accomplish this

I tried tesseract *.tif *
which gives me this
read_params_file: parameter not found: II*

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overwriting the output file for every new page, I did:

```
for i in *tif; do b=`basename "$i" .tif`; tesseract "$i" "$b" hocr; done
```

It worked fine.

(I found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/cHqlzcmT7Lg).)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works

```
for i in *.tif ; do tesseract $i outtext;  done;
```

Make sure when you are in terminal you change directory to the location of all of the tif files.

Comment: doesn't work does the same as <code>tesseract input output</code> I tried replacing outtext as * but that doesn't work either. Just renders that error

Comment: Then reinstall tesseract as it worked for me unless you are using a really old version.

Comment: I reformatted my linux OS and did an install of ubuntu. Grabbed synaptic package manager, then did a sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade. Then rebooted. Then wen't on to install tesseract-ocr in synaptic. Works, but keeps overwriting the file for every new page.

Comment: I'm running 12.10 64bit, what version are you running?

Comment: Does it even give you an error if you do it on one file? If so upload file and I can try to see if its the file thats causing the issue

Comment: These files were converted from .png to .tif.  steven@steven-Ideapad-Z575:~/Documents/cbtif/ultratest/hocr2test$ tesseract 9.tif 9
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
Page 0
steven@steven-Ideapad-Z575:~/Documents/cbtif/ultratest/hocr2test$ 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/spbv6h

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net), which uses Tesseract and supports batch/bulk OCR.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted convert Kannada (Indian language) as searchable pdf

I modified this
for i in *tif; do b=`basename "$i" .tif`; tesseract "$i" "$b" hocr; done

AS BELOW

for i in *tif; do b=`basename "$i" .tif`; tesseract  -l kan "$i" "$b" pdf; done

It worked well for the entire folder was converted from image to searchable pdf
Tnakyou